# Simple **Unsolvable** electric field problem

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, maxwell-equations

**Cannot be integrated w Coulomb, Maxwell doesn’t work. Impossible situation?**

So then what would really happen?

Large sheet of charge (assume infinite or far from edges, and even assume low but nonzero charge density). Now add a parallel sheet of copper just above it, some thickness.

The copper’s charges migrate until no field remains inside to move them. How do they move? What is the charge distribution across the thickness?

Comment: Why do you think it's unsolvable, ie what have you actually tried vs claiming you cannot do it with any of the tools available to you (Hint Gauss' law works perfectly fine here).

Comment: Funny people keep downvoting cuz so easy but cant solve it

Comment: Why do you think that electric charges piling up on one side add to the field? The field points in the opposite direction inside the conducting plane, and since the electric field is a vector, these fields cancel to leave the interior of the conductor free of electric field as must be required. You can then use Gauss' law to find the charge needed to do so.

Comment: I didnt realize we could create positive charges with holes. I did but forgot. Lol. Tried deleting this. Not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the sheet of charge have positive charge. Then negative charges in the copper move toward the sheet.

What you’re missing is that there can be the equivalent of mobile positive charges too. If we assume the sheet is positively charged, we can put enough negative charge on the “sheet side” of the copper (nearest to the charged sheet) to contribute E/2 within the copper, and the same amount of positive charge on the outer side of the copper.

Positive charges in the copper accumulate on the other side. E field inside the copper is 0.

Any layer of charge causes a typical $E_{0} = \frac{\sigma_{0}}{2\epsilon}$ field.

Between the sheet and copper is $E_{0}$ due to the sheet, the fields due to the positive and negative charges of the copper cancel each other out, since they are opposite charges in the same direction.

In the copper layer, the field must be 0. $E_{0}$ from the sheet, $-E_{0}/2$  from the negative charges in the same direction as the sheet, $-E_{0}$ from the positive charges in the opposite direction as the sheet.

On the opposite side of the copper layer, the field will be $E_{0}$ again, since the flux due to the copper charges cancel out once again.

Comment: What do you mean by drawing a boundary through the copper?

Comment: (Positive charge sheet) (Negative charge) (Copper Body) (Positive Charge)

Positive Charge sheet pushes Right. 
Negative Charge 2 Pulls left (partially countering positive charge sheet)
Positive Charge 2 pushes left (partially countering positive charge sheet)

Charges 2 are equal and add to zero because they come from charge separation in the copper plate.

Comment: The charges on the sides of the copper body are on the edges/boundary of the copper.

Comment: Thats what i was missing. I was trying to do it with electrons only, thinking you dont have free positive charges

Comment: great :) 

yup, absence of an electron creates a hole which is essentially a positive charge. so even though protons in a metal are not moving around freely, anywhere with a hole has insufficient negative charge to balance the protons that are there.

Comment: So all the charge has to come from the edge of the sheet, and i defined it such that there is enough there to do so

Comment: I cant tell if you accepted the edit. (?) was gonna checkmark it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128610/discussion-between-alwin-and-al-brown).